# Persisting Radio Button State

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The code below represents a search form structure inside a PartialView. The Partial View is rendered in multiple pages. Any postpack causes the selected radio button to being reset to the first one. How to persist the state of the selected radio button in this case?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller"))
{

        <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Options<span class="test"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu ui-tabs-active">
                <li><input id="All" type="radio" checked="checked" value="Value1" name="SelectedOptions"> <span>Option 1</span></li>
                <li><input type="radio" value="Value2" name="SelectedOptions"> <span>Option 2</span></li>
                <li><input type="radio" value="value3" name="SelectedOptions"> <span>Option 3</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input id="search-box" type="text">
        <button id="search-button" class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-search" formmethod="post"></button>
}
```

Comment: Bind it to a view model property.

Comment: You don't need javascript. You just need to bind you radio buttons to a model property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, can you please explain or at least point to an example.

Comment: Without more context its hard to know what will be the best solution, but essentially you need view model to bind to that contains properties `string SelectedOption` so that you can use `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedOption, ....)` for each value. Then when you submit and return another view, you can set the value of `model.SelectedOption` to the posted value and the previous selection will be correctly bound